# Can you get data from a database with inno setup?

Tags: database, inno-setup

I am currently trying to create an installer that first needs to check the license of the user, but the license is on a database. so the installer asks for the license, the user gives an input and the installer will search for the license in the database. based on the outcome of that it can proceed or not.

Is it possible to do this with Inno setup or do i need to get an additional or different program entirely.

sidenote: the database isn't on my computer you can acces it online with the right link.

Comment: *"the database isn't on my computer you can acces it online with the right link."* – So a database or a website? – What is the API?

Comment: It's a database

Comment: Sorry, that's vague. What database? What is the API? How would you access the database in your favorite programming language?

Comment: We need more info.

Comment: My know that the MySQL driver can be used to access an online database by using credentials. I used it with Visual C++ MFC. But don't know if that is relevant here.